# Create table in tablespace

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have created tablespace named CUSTOMER using EM Express, but when I have tried to create table in that tablespace I am receiving tablespace CUSTOMER does not exist.

```
create table customer
     (id numerical,
     name varchar2 (30))
     tablespace customer;
```

I have tried to write CUSTOMER or customer, results would be the same. Tablespace does not exist

[image: em exprres]

[image: sqlplus]

Comment: Are you sure both sessions are connected to the same database?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure, how should I check that? @Alex Poole

Comment: You can query `USER_TABLESPACES` from the command prompt window where you executed your 'CREATE TABLE` statement to check if you see `CUSTOMER` tablespace or not.